# How to process images of different sizes using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to process images pixel-by-pixel just like the convolution operation. However, when I do it as follow with Tensorflow,

```
height = tf.shape(img)[0]
width = tf.shape(img)[1]
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        patch = img[h:h+filter_sz, w:w+filter_sz, :]
```

I got an error: "Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. " As images are of different sizes, I can not fix height and width when construct the computational graph. How should I do it? Or, why tf.nn.conv2d and tf.nn.max_pool can handle images of different sizes?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The output of `tf.shape` is a `Tensor`, which means it is lazy, which means it will not be calculated until you call `sess.run`. To get the shape of a `Tensor` when defining graph, you should call `Tensor.get_shape()` which will return a `TensorShape`. So the code above should be change to:

```
height, width = img.get_shape()
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        patch = img[h:h+filter_sz, w:w+filter_sz, :]
```

Comment: But my problem is that I cannot know the shape of images (since they are of different sizes) when defining the graph. The img is defined as: img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32). So, there is no shape information in it.

Comment: Then you should try `tf.while_loop`, which could loop on tensor.